# Using .NET Rx to observe property changed with Action events

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Say I am using the following interface (assume we can't change our implementation to make it `IObservable<T>` as well as `IProperty<T>`).

```
public interface IProperty<T> {
    T Value { get; set; }
    event Action ValueChanged;
}
```

I am trying to observe the collection of `T`s generated as the value changes. Because the event is declared as `Action` rather than the standard .NET event pattern I don't think I can use `Observable.FromEvent(...)`.

I've come up with a wrapper that seems to work, but as an Rx newbie I'm sure I'm missing some built in abstractions (or am possibly just doing the whole thing wrong).

Is there any way to do this using built in Rx functionality? If not, is my wrapper missing any obvious abstractions, or is there a completely different approach I should be taking?

```
//Example wrapper
public class ObservableProperty<T> : IObservable<T> {
    private readonly IProperty<T> _property;
    public ObservableProperty(IProperty<T> property) { _property = property; }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) {
        Action action = () => observer.OnNext(_property.Value);
        _property.ValueChanged += action;
        return Disposable.Create(() => _property.ValueChanged -= action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static class RxExt
{
    public static IObservable<T> FromMyEvent<T>(this IProperty<T> src)
    {
        return System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Create<T>((obs) =>
        {
            Action eh = () => obs.OnNext(src.Value);
            src.ValueChanged += eh;
            return () => src.ValueChanged -= eh;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch. Now why couldn't I figure that out? :)

Comment: One of my Rx guidelines is "never implement IObservable or IObserver directly" - that restriction helps force me to find the simpler way w/ the build in api

Comment: Given the way that this will likely be used `property.FromMyEvent(...)`, I would name the method `ToObservable`, but other than that it looks like what I would do.

Comment: Scott gives good advice - implementing IObservable is kind of like implementing IEnumerable - rarely it's what you should do, but more likely it means you should use a class that already exists like Subject